# .BAT file to loop through numbers - Need to add 0 to numbers less than 10

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a number of .bat files that are opening a program and finding a specific instance that is ran everyday.  This instance is timestamped and changes everyday.  So I am having the .bat file run through everynumber looking for that instance.  The format is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

From this site I already have a .bat file that finds the previous business day.  I even have it looping through the numbers

The problem is if the number is less than 10, it needs to have a 0 in front of it:
01,02,03,04 etc...
  The way the .bat file spits it out, though, is 1,2,3 etc...
  Here is the code I have so far:

```
For /L %%G IN (3,1,9) DO (
    For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
        If %%H LSS 10 SET %%H=0%%H
            ECHO %prevbusday%0%%G%%H
    )
)
timeout /t 60
```

The first line loops through the hours (3 to 9)
The nested formula then loops through the minutes (0 to 59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify `%%H` directly.  You have to set `"variable=%%H"` and use delayed expansion to retrieve `!variable!`.  As long as you're setting another variable anyway, just use variable substrings.  Prepend a zero to everything, then use the rightmost two digits.

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /L %%G IN (3,1,9) DO (
    For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
        set "h=0%%H"
        ECHO %prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!
    )
)
timeout /t 60
```

Comment: I could have check marked either of these 2 answers.  They both do exactly what I needed them to do.  Thank you rojo, I like your method of using the rightmost two digits.  This is straightforward and uncomplicated.

Comment: It's OK.  Rafael needs the karma anyway.  :)

Comment: I am going to post a followup question under a new thread.  I figure I should just keep appending to this thread because you both answered the question.

Comment: I ended up using your code because I felt it was cleaner.  So I check marked your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling delayedexpansion then setting a new varialbe inside your inner `for` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /L %%G IN (3,1,9) DO (
    For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
        If %%H LSS 10 (SET hours=0%%H) else (SET hours=%%H)
            ECHO %prevbusday%0%%G!hours!
pause
    )
)
timeout /t 60
```

Don't forget to use exclamation marks for your new varialbe within the inner `for` loop

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked just fine and is exactly what I was looking for.  The syntax is really difficult for me with these .bat files.  Ill look into delayedexpansion now!