# .bat file - Write a new variable to a .msl (.txt) file

Tags: batch-file

OK, so this is a follow-up to [another question I had earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170213/).  My code finds the previous business day and then loops through all the hour-minute combinations between 3 and 9.

The code will feed this new variable into a .msl (basically a .txt file for our document direct server).

I need the code to write the found variable into the .msl file and run the file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo wd = Weekday^(Date^(^), vbSunday^)>yesterday.vbs
echo if wd ^< 3 then dif = -1 - wd else dif = -1 >>yesterday.vbs
echo d = dateadd^("d", dif, Date^(^)^)>>yesterday.vbs
echo wscript.echo DatePart^("yyyy",d^) ^& " " ^& DatePart^("m", d^) ^& " " ^& DatePart^("d", d^) >>yesterday.vbs
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%I in ('cscript /nologo yesterday.vbs') do (
    set year=%%I
    if %%J leq 9 (set month=0%%J) else set month=%%J
    if %%K leq 9 (set day=0%%K) else set day=%%K
)
del yesterday.vbs
set YYYY=%year:~-4%
set MM=%month:~-2%
set DD=%day:~-2%

set prevbusday=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%

echo %prevbusday%

pause

For /L %%G IN (3,1,9) DO (
    For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
        set "h=0%%H"
        ECHO %prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!
        set "id=%prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!"
        break>test.msl
        (echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'TrialReports ' VERSIONID ' **id** 'SECTIONID ' 0000-000 Name of Report' PAGE 1)> test.msl
        (echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'C:\New folder\check.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> test.msl

        (echo CLOSE) >> test.msl
        rem **Here I will add the code to call the newly minted 'test.msl' - but
        rem   I'll get to that later** 

    )
)

pause
```

Where is says `VERSIONID ' id` Is where I need to inject the variable. 
I've tried to do this in quotes and what not and can't figure out how to inject it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows variables are evaluated inline.  All you have to do is replace `**id**` with `!id!`.

Just so I feel like I've done something useful, I'll help you with that previous business day calculation as well.  You can hybridize the code and use a JScript `Date()` object to remove the necessity of echoing out to a temporary .vbs script.  I also moved the redirect to `test.msl` to a parenthetical code block to clean up the code a bit.  If your MSL handler allows, you can dump all your `OPENVIEW...EXPORT...CLOSE` lines to a file and only run the handler once, which might improve efficiency.  See [revision 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30174250/2) for an example.

I think this does what you want.  Save it with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do set "prevbusday=%%I"

echo %prevbusday%
pause

For /L %%G IN (3,1,9) DO (
    For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
        set "h=0%%H"
        set "id=%prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!"
        echo !id!

        >test.msl (
            echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'TrialReports ' VERSIONID ' !id! ' SECTIONID ' 0000-000 Name of Report' PAGE 1
            echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'C:\New folder\check.rpt' CURSEC GROUP ''
            echo CLOSE
        )

        rem **Here I will add the code to call the newly minted 'test.msl' - but
        rem   I'll get to that later** 

    )
)

pause

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    yesterday = new Date().getDay() - 1,
    prevbusday = new Date(!yesterday?new Date()-day*3:(yesterday<0?new Date()-day*2:new Date()-day)),
    y = [
        prevbusday.getFullYear(),
        ('0' + (prevbusday.getMonth() + 1)).match(/\d\d$/)[0],
        ('0' + prevbusday.getDate()).match(/\d\d$/)[0]
    ]

WSH.Echo(y.join(''));
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is perfect.  I apprecaite the little flourish with the JScript.

Comment: Yeah, about that.  I just fixed a problem with my logic.  It works fine today, but tomorrow you'd probably get an error.  Use the latest edit, please.  :)

Comment: I posted my final code as an answer below - I hope that is appropriate.  I want you to have the credit due.  Should I have posted my answer here as a comment to your post?

Comment: I find batch files to be difficult to get a grasp on.  For example: Why can you reference some variables with %x% and others (like in your edits) !id!?  Do you have any tips for familiarizing myself better with the syntax and nuances of the code?

Comment: `%variables%` are expanded before the commands they live within are evaluated. `!variables!` require `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and aren't expanded until runtime. Here's a [pretty good explanation](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Mostly, delayed expansion is used within parenthetical code blocks (i.e. `for` loops), where the variable's value changed within that block.  It's also used to prevent special characters from being evaluated prematurely (like HTML tags and percents).  Delayed expansion can mangle exclamation marks, though, so it's typically only used when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final code base on @rojo's edits.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem // invoke JScript chimera to get the YYYYMMDD of the previous work day
for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do set "prevbusday=%%I"

echo %prevbusday%

pause

type NUL > test.msl

For /L %%G IN (3,1,9) DO (
    For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
        set "h=0%%H"
        type NUL > test.msl
        ECHO %prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!
        set "id=%prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!"

        (echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'TestReports ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0000-000 Name of Report' PAGE 1)>> test.msl
        (echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'C:\New folder\check.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '')>> test.msl

        (echo CLOSE) >> test.msl

        PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
        Start test.msl

        PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
        start passwordinjector.vbs

        PING 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1
        IF EXIST "C:\New folder\check.rpt" (
            echo It exists!

            taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe /f >nul 2>&1

            PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
            Start Trial.msl

            PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
            start passwordinjector.vbs

            PING 1.1.1.1 -w 3000 -n 1
            Del "C:\Desktop\New folder\check.rpt"
            exit
        ) ELSE (
            echo It doesn't exist :(
            PING 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1
            taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe /f >nul 2>&1
        )
    )
)

pause

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
yesterday = new Date().getDay() - 1,
prevbusday = new Date(!yesterday?new Date()-day*3:(yesterday<0?new Date()-    day*2:new Date()-day)),
y = [
    prevbusday.getFullYear(),
    ('0' + (prevbusday.getMonth() + 1)).match(/\d\d$/)[0],
    ('0' + prevbusday.getDate()).match(/\d\d$/)[0]
]

WSH.Echo(y.join(''));
```