# Batch file to run while windows is locked

Tags: batch-file

OK, so this is a follow-up to [another question I had earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173423/).  My code finds the previous business day and then loops through all the hour-minute combinations between 3 and 9.

The code feeds this new variable into a .msl (basically a .txt file for our document direct server).

That if the right combination of hour-minute numbers is right, it will spit out a check report.

My code checks for that report in each loop.  As soon as it finds that 'check' report, it needs to write to a larger .msl file with the main code to pull the main reports.

Question:
I need this to run overnight, when my computer is locked. I have it set up to run automatically with Windows Task Scheduler.  I am not logged out, the computer is locked. Right now, the batch file errors out when it gets to `type NUL > test.msl`.  I think this has to do with the file being unavailable to write to from the lock screen. I was wondering if there is a way to write in the entire file path of the `test.msl`. Like `C:\UserID\folder\test.msl` and execute that.

Here is what I have so far, this code works perfect when I manually start it but not when scheduled to run while the computer is locked:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem // invoke JScript chimera to get the YYYYMMDD of the previous work day
for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do set "prevbusday=%%I"

echo %prevbusday%

type NUL > test.msl
type NUL > DailyFile.msl
For /L %%G IN (3,1,8) DO (
For /L %%H IN (0,1,59) DO (
set "h=0%%H"
type NUL > test.msl
    ECHO %prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!
    set "id=%prevbusday%0%%G!h:~-2!"

    (echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0000-006 FILE/TABLE ERRORS' PAGE 1)>> test.msl
    (echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Document Direct Automation\Check\check.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '')>> test.msl

    (echo CLOSE) >> test.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
Start test.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
start passwordinjector.vbs

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1
IF EXIST "S:\Automation\Document Direct Automation\Check\check.rpt" (

echo It exists!

taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe /f >nul 2>&1

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1

    pause
(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0019-001 069' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\c&d.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl

(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0019-001 0' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\exec hold.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl

(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0019-001 65' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\fl outreach rev.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl

(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 1144-001' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\litigation.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl

(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0291-001 CASE' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\lm flag.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl

(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0019-001' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\recourse.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl

(echo OPENVIEW SERVERID 'Mobius Server     ' REPORTID 'MGREPORTS ' VERSIONID ' !id! 'SECTIONID ' 0285-002 ' PAGE 1) >> DailyFile.msl
(echo EXPORT ASCII FILE 'S:\Automation\Monarch\repay.rpt' CURSEC GROUP '') >> DailyFile.msl
(echo CLOSE) >> DailyFile.msl


(echo RUN "S:\Automation\BAT files\daily.bat") >> DailyFile.msl


    PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
Start DailyFile.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
start passwordinjector.vbs

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 3000 -n 1
Del "S:\Check\check.rpt"
exit

) ELSE (
echo It doesn't exist :(
PING 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1
taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe /f >nul 2>&1

)


)
)



goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
yesterday = new Date().getDay() - 1,
prevbusday = new Date(!yesterday?new Date()-day*3:(yesterday<0?new Date()-day*2:new Date()-day)),
y = [
    prevbusday.getFullYear(),
    ('0' + (prevbusday.getMonth() + 1)).match(/\d\d$/)[0],
    ('0' + prevbusday.getDate()).match(/\d\d$/)[0]
]

WSH.Echo(y.join(''));
```

Comment: What scheduling tool is being used? Is the user logged out?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler.  The user is not logged out, the system is set to lock windows after a certain amount of time.

Comment: What was the result of specifying a fully qualified path to the ouput test.txt file?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it exaclty.  I tried C:\UserID\folder\test.msl and with quotes "C:\UserID\folder\test.msl" and neither work.  The cmd window shows `Access is denied.` for each `type NUL` but continues to the next line.  An error window pops up when the code hits `Start test.msl`.  The error window says "Windows cannot find 'test.msl'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Comment: Is the destination file in your (logged in) user directory? If it is in another user's directory structure, you might not have permission to write there.

Comment: Its flexible.  I've tried it on our network drives both referencing the drive name (S:\) and the actual network name (\\dm000\networkname\shares\ _for example_).  I've also tried it on my own desktop (C:\user\username\desktop).  None of them work.  Again, I am flexible, I can have it launch the code from my desktop or the network drive.

Comment: When you right-click on the scheduled task and view properties, what user account is it using? Is it set to run only when the user is logged in? Please check the other items on the various tabbed pages.